# Page limit using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm having an issue when using rvest to scrape 466 pages from a wiki. Each page represents a metric that I need further information about.  I have the following code which loops through each link (loaded from a csv file) and extracts the information I need from a html table on each page.

```
Metrics <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\WebScraping\\LONMetrics.csv")

    Metrics$Theme <- as.character(paste0(Metrics$Theme))
    Metrics$Metric <- as.character(paste0(Metrics$Metric))
    Metrics$URL <- as.character(paste0(Metrics$URL))

    n = nrow(Metrics)

    i = 1

    while (i <= n) {
      webPage <- read_html(Metrics$URL[i])
      pageTable <- html_table(webpage)
      Metrics$Definition[i] <- pageTable[[1]]$X2[1]
      Metrics$Category[i] <- pageTable[[1]]$X2[2]
      Metrics$Calculation[i] <- pageTable[[1]]$X2[3]
      Metrics$UOM[i] <- pageTable[[1]]$X2[4]
      Metrics$ExpectedTrend[i] <- pageTable[[1]]$X2[6]
      Metrics$MinTech[i] <- pageTable[[1]]$X2[7]
      i = i+1
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that it stops returning data after 32 pages giving an error as:

> Error in read_connection_(x, n) :
>   Evaluation error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

I'm wondering what the cause may be and how to get around this seeming limitation?

Thanks.

Rob

Comment: Hi RobE, is there any way you can make this problem reproducible, for example to provide a subset (3 or 4) of the CSV so people here can run it on their own machines? I think that will help you get some answers. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi RobE, is there any way you can make this problem reproducible, for example to provide a subset (3 or 4) of the CSV so people here can run it on their own machines? I think that will help you get some answers. Thanks :)

Comment: Switch from using `xml2::read_html()` to `httr::GET()` (you have to use `httr::content()` on the results of the `GET`) and you have access to more diagnostics about the connection and can even turn on verbose logging to see even more detail.

Comment: Thanks @mysteRious unfortunately I can't provide the pages as they are propriety (yes - I have legitimate access).  I think that a block was put on by the website as it wouldn't return any at all after that - even when using a different IP.  I managed to get around the issue with RSelenium so all good.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr I'll give that a try when using rvest again.